# Разница между обработчиком и запуском события

Tags: jquery

В jquery документации всегда при описании метода указывается "Устанавливает обработчик ... элементов документа, либо, запускает это событие." 
Например: 
.scroll()
Устанавливает обработчик "прокрутки" элементов документа, либо, запускает это событие.
Что значит обработчик "прокрутки" и что значит запуск события? В чем их разница?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Когда используеться выражение `scroll()` - происходит запуск события, то есть прокрутка, а когда используеться `scroll(function(event){....})`, тогда назначаеться обработчик. Это более понятно на примере с `click()`.

Answer (score 0):

Установить обработчик означает что будет производится слушание действий на странице, простыми словами - ожидание и слежение наступления требуемого действия (event). 
В вашем случае если установлен обработчик "прокрутки", то страница будет ждать наступления прокрутки страницы. Как только будет выполнена прокрутка, обработчик это увидит и выполнит заданное в нем событие.

Answer (score 0):

При вызове с параметром `click(handler)`, функция добавляет обработчик события, а при вызове без параметров `click()` вызывает само событие аналогично `trigger('click')`, что означает вызов всех обработчиков этого события (только jQuery'ных, нативные не вызовутся).